# Save a volume in HDR format

Tags: matlab, file, volume, hdr

I am analyzing some MRI data, which are stored in HDR format (M by N by L volumes). 
After several computation, I would like to save a volume (MxNxL) in HDR format. 
How can I do that? 
makehdr wants a collection, hdrwrite works with MxNx3 volumes.

By the way, I'm using MATLAB.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to write [Analyze files](http://web.archive.org/web/20070927191351/http://www.mayo.edu/bir/PDF/ANALYZE75.pdf)? Analyze is a medical imaging format which saves a *.hdr and *.img pair of files. Matlab's hdrwrite stores [High Dynamic Range images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hdrwrite.html).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Sorry, I'm still new to the subject.

Comment: Saving data in Analyze 7.5 has can be easily found with a google search. If you wish to write your own utility you can consult the above link which describes the file format. Or there are utilities already made: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1878-mri-analyze-tools) or [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image) or [here](http://www.neuro.mcw.edu/~chumphri/matlab/writeanalyze.m)